# GDP per capita of areas formerly belonging to East Germany vs those of northern England

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, comparative-politics, gdp

The BBC [wrote](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-60216307) (at beginning of Feb) regarding UK's "levelling up" plan:

> The problem that the government seeks to solve with its "levelling up" agenda is clear - the fact that the UK is one of the world's most geographically unequal major economies - and that has worsened over the past three decades. [...]
>
> But where a mission such as this has been achieved, for example in post-unification Germany, there have been massive fiscal transfers from rich regions to poor ones approaching one and a half trillion pounds, or £70bn a year.
>
> The stark fact is that GDP per capita in some east German regions now exceeds that in some northern English regions.

In that last sentence, I suppose the repetition of the word "some" qualifying the extent of the comparison for both areas is significant. So, how is one to circumscribe that comparison in more concrete terms/areas in order to make it true? And is this comparison far from being true "on average" between those regions?

Comment: As a side remark, 70bn pounds a year is a slightly low estimate. In the first 20 years after reunification it was more around 100bn Euros a year. It may be less now.

Comment: @quarague during the period in question 100 bn euros was probably worth just about 70 bn pounds.  Between 1999 and 2009, the rate was mostly around 1.6 for a few years, then 1.45 before dropping to 1.26 and 1.12 in 2008-2009.  For most of the 90s, the DEM was around 35 to 45 pence, putting the Euro at 68 to 88 pence and the pound at 1.14 to 1.47 euros.  100 to 70 implies an average exchange rate of 1.43, so just about right.

Comment: Are these really comparable?  France has similar issues to the UK, wrt Paris' economic weight.  They've also adjusted on the margins - things like opening new government agencies in different regions.  But, and that is a big but, this has been a partial project that isn't a full on commitment.  When Germany was reunified, the electorate knew full well what they were committing to.  The old marks got exchanged, minimum wages normalized, etc...  This was a big clear once-in-a-generation project.  A moonshot if you will.  Is the UK committed to funding that?  If not, can they be compared?

Answer (score 12):

This is plausible if you look at German states compared to UK regions. If you look at smaller geographic areas it becomes trivially true due to bigger variance.

First I consider nominal GDP per capita. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(nominal)_per_capita), GDP per capita in Germany as a whole is about 5 to 10% higher than GDP per capita in the UK, depending on whether you use IMF, UN or World Bank data.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_German_states_by_GRP_per_capita) also has data on GDP per capita for each of the German states. The wealthiest state in former East Germany is Saxony at around 75% of the German value.

Finally, [here](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1168072/uk-gdp-per-head-by-region/) is a list of GDP per capita in UK regions, the poorest one is the North East at around 75% of the UK value.

Put together that means that GDP per capita in Saxony is a few percent higher than in the North East region of the UK.

Comment: +1. Actually, the link for UK GDP per capita tells us that the North East (GDP 23,109 GBP = 27,148 EUR) is lower than that of *all* German states, the worst-off of which has a GDP of 28,800 EUR. And the same holds for Wales (23,882 GBP = 28,067 EUR). Of course, simple comparisons of GDP need to be taken with a grain of salt, one should really adjust for purchasing power, and that will be nontrivial on a regional level.

Comment: This is a good answer, but, out of curiosity, are [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purchasing_power_parity)-adjusted numbers (or an analogue of them) available? These are often more useful than nominal ones when comparing GDP/capita between different regions. I'm not sure if anything like it is tracked in the UK and/or Germany, but the USA keeps track of a measure called "Regional Price Parity," which is just the equivalent of PPP factors, but for regions smaller than the entire country (e.g. states, metro areas, etc.)

Comment: @reirab I deliberately chose nominal over some purchasing power adjusted numbers because this gives you a well-defined answer. Trying to adjusting for purchasing power requires so many choices and in the end at best you adjust for some kind of average which isn't really representative for most individuals. Nominal has its draw backs because it is not adjusted for different prices but it is an objective measure. PPP is subjective.

Comment: @quarague Yeah, nominal is certainly more objectively measurable, though usually considerably less meaningful when comparing numbers between places where prices are not at least very similar (I don't know whether that's true of Northern England vs. Eastern Germany or not, just speaking in general.) A 50,000 GBP income in London would be extremely different from a 50,000 GBP in rural parts of the U.K. in terms of standard of living, though, for example.

Comment: @reirab, but so is 50 k€ in Munich vs. 50 k€ in Sachsen-Anhalt

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Of course. My point was just that without a regional-level PPP adjustment, it's not clear how meaningful direct comparisons of GDP/capita figures are between East German regions and Northern English ones. The nominal differences might translate into real ones, but they also might not, especially when we're talking about differences potentially as small as 5% Regionals prices often vary by _much_ more than that.